# Dropdown navbar subitems overlap datatable causing it to look transparent

Tags: javascript, html, css, datatables-1.10

I am working on a website with a page that shows the navbar on top and a datatable underneath. However, when I hover over the navbar which causes the subitems to drop down, I notice the parts that overlap the datatable, look almost transparent.

I have added the code of a simplified version of my webpage as well as some screenshot to visualize the problem I am facing. What is causing this problem and how can I solve it?

[image: desktop mode]

[image: responsive mode]

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.6.0/dt-1.13.4/fc-4.2.2/fh-3.3.2/r-2.4.1/datatables.min.css"/>
        <style>
            #container {
              margin: 0 auto;
              max-width: 1100px;
            }

            .toggle, [id^=drop] {
              display: none;
            }

            nav {
              margin: 0;
              padding: 0;
              background-color: #0177bf;
            }

            #logo {
              display: block;
              padding: 0 30px;
              float: left;
              font-size: 20px;
              line-height: 60px;
            }

            nav:after {
              content: "";
              display: table;
              clear: both;
            }

            nav ul {
              float: left;
              padding: 0;
              margin: 0;
              list-style: none;
              position: relative;
            }

            nav ul li {
              margin: 0px;
              display: inline-block;
              float: left;
              background-color: #0177bf;
            }

            nav a {
              display: block;
              padding: 0 10px;
              color: #FFF;
              font-size: 15px;
              line-height: 60px;
              text-decoration: none;
            }

            nav ul li ul li:hover { background: #026dae; color: white; }

            nav a:hover { background-color: #026dae; color: white; }

            nav ul ul {
              display: none;
              position: absolute;
              top: 60px;
            }

            nav ul li:hover > ul { display: inherit; color: white; }

            nav ul ul li {
              float: none;
              display: list-item;
              position: relative;
            }

            nav ul ul ul li {
              position: relative;
              top: -60px;
              left: 170px;
            }

            li > a:only-child:after { content: ''; }

            /* Media Queries
            --------------------------------------------- */
            @media all and (max-width : 768px) {

                #logo {
                  display: block;
                  padding: 0;
                  width: 100%;
                  text-align: center;
                  float: none;
                }

                nav {
                    margin: 0;
                }

                .toggle + a,
                 .menu { display: none; position: absolute; }

                .toggle {
                  display: block;
                  background-color: #0177bf;
                  padding: 0 10px;
                  color: #FFF;
                  font-size: 22px;
                  font-weight:bold;
                  line-height: 60px;
                  text-decoration: none;
                  border: none;
                }

                [id^=drop]:checked + ul { display: block; }

                nav ul li {
                  display: block;
                  width: 100%;
                }

                nav ul ul .toggle,
                 nav ul ul a { padding: 0 40px; }

                nav ul ul ul a { padding: 0 80px; }

                nav ul ul {
                  float: none;
                  position: static;
                  color: #ffffff;
                }

                nav ul ul li:hover > ul,
                nav ul li:hover > ul { display: none; color: white;}

                nav ul ul li {
                  display: block;
                  width: 100%;
                }

                nav ul ul ul li { position: static; }

                @media all and (max-width : 330px) {
                    nav ul li {
                      display: block;
                      width: 94%;
                    }
                }
            }
        </style>

        <!-- JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.6.0/dt-1.13.4/fc-4.2.2/fh-3.3.2/r-2.4.1/datatables.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#membersTable').DataTable({
                    responsive: true,
                    pageLength: 25
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <label for="drop" class="toggle">&#8801; Menu</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li>
                    <label for="drop-1" class="toggle">Ticket Management</label>
                    <a href="#">Ticket Management</a>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1"/>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/members">Add New Tickets</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/member?action=new">Sell Tickets</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="drop-2" class="toggle">Event Management</label>
                    <a href="#">Event Management</a>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-2"/>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/events">Event Calendar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/event?action=new">Add New Event</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/my-events">My Events</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div class="container">
            <table id="membersTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                <thead id="membersTableHeaders">
                    <tr>
                        <th data-priority="2"></th>
                        <th data-priority="1"></th>
                        <th data-priority="1"></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th data-priority="2"></th>
                        <th data-priority="2"></th>
                        <th data-priority="2"></th>
                        <th data-priority="1"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: someone forgot to use `z-index`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nav is declared first in the HTML so it's underneath everything else. You need to set `z-index` to something high, but not higher than modals, and with that you need to set `position` anything other than `static`.

```
nav{
  position: relative;
  z-index: 999;
}
```

```html
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.6.0/dt-1.13.4/fc-4.2.2/fh-3.3.2/r-2.4.1/datatables.min.css"/>
        <style>
            #container {
              margin: 0 auto;
              max-width: 1100px;
            }

            .toggle, [id^=drop] {
              display: none;
            }

            nav {
              margin: 0;
              padding: 0;
              background-color: #0177bf;
position: relative;
z-index: 999;
            }

            #logo {
              display: block;
              padding: 0 30px;
              float: left;
              font-size: 20px;
              line-height: 60px;
            }

            nav:after {
              content: "";
              display: table;
              clear: both;
            }

            nav ul {
              float: left;
              padding: 0;
              margin: 0;
              list-style: none;
              position: relative;
            }

            nav ul li {
              margin: 0px;
              display: inline-block;
              float: left;
              background-color: #0177bf;
            }

            nav a {
              display: block;
              padding: 0 10px;
              color: #FFF;
              font-size: 15px;
              line-height: 60px;
              text-decoration: none;
            }

            nav ul li ul li:hover { background: #026dae; color: white; }

            nav a:hover { background-color: #026dae; color: white; }

            nav ul ul {
              display: none;
              position: absolute;
              top: 60px;
            }

            nav ul li:hover > ul { display: inherit; color: white; }

            nav ul ul li {
              float: none;
              display: list-item;
              position: relative;
            }

            nav ul ul ul li {
              position: relative;
              top: -60px;
              left: 170px;
            }

            li > a:only-child:after { content: ''; }

            /* Media Queries
            --------------------------------------------- */
            @media all and (max-width : 768px) {

                #logo {
                  display: block;
                  padding: 0;
                  width: 100%;
                  text-align: center;
                  float: none;
                }

                nav {
                    margin: 0;
                }

                .toggle + a,
                 .menu { display: none; position: absolute; }

                .toggle {
                  display: block;
                  background-color: #0177bf;
                  padding: 0 10px;
                  color: #FFF;
                  font-size: 22px;
                  font-weight:bold;
                  line-height: 60px;
                  text-decoration: none;
                  border: none;
                }

                [id^=drop]:checked + ul { display: block; }

                nav ul li {
                  display: block;
                  width: 100%;
                }

                nav ul ul .toggle,
                 nav ul ul a { padding: 0 40px; }

                nav ul ul ul a { padding: 0 80px; }

                nav ul ul {
                  float: none;
                  position: static;
                  color: #ffffff;
                }

                nav ul ul li:hover > ul,
                nav ul li:hover > ul { display: none; color: white;}

                nav ul ul li {
                  display: block;
                  width: 100%;
                }

                nav ul ul ul li { position: static; }

                @media all and (max-width : 330px) {
                    nav ul li {
                      display: block;
                      width: 94%;
                    }
                }
            }
        </style>

        <!-- JavaScript -->
        <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/v/dt/jq-3.6.0/dt-1.13.4/fc-4.2.2/fh-3.3.2/r-2.4.1/datatables.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $('#membersTable').DataTable({
                    responsive: true,
                    pageLength: 25
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <nav>
            <label for="drop" class="toggle">&#8801; Menu</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="drop" />
            <ul class="menu">
                <li><a href="/dashboard">Dashboard</a></li>
                <li>
                    <label for="drop-1" class="toggle">Ticket Management</label>
                    <a href="#">Ticket Management</a>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-1"/>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/members">Add New Tickets</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/member?action=new">Sell Tickets</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <label for="drop-2" class="toggle">Event Management</label>
                    <a href="#">Event Management</a>
                    <input type="checkbox" id="drop-2"/>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/events">Event Calendar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/event?action=new">Add New Event</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/my-events">My Events</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <div class="container">
            <table id="membersTable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
                <thead id="membersTableHeaders">
                    <tr>
                        <th data-priority="2"></th>
                        <th data-priority="1"></th>
                        <th data-priority="1"></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th></th>
                        <th data-priority="2"></th>
                        <th data-priority="2"></th>
                        <th data-priority="2"></th>
                        <th data-priority="1"></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes ofcourse, so stupid of me! In my defense, I am Java back-end developer so not used to front-end stuff xD. Thanks for the solution!